# I want to check if username has any Character from blockCharacter but i could'nt do it

Tags: python

I want to check if username has any Character from blockCharacter but i could'nt do it and this is my code

```
user = input("Whats your name\n").lower()
user = (user.title())
BlockChar = ["+","none","-"]
if user == BlockChar:
  print("That does'nt not feels right. Try Again")
  breakpoint
print ("Welcome " + user)
```

I am new to codeing and stack overflow so i need some help with it

Comment: Clearly, if the user enters "abc+def", that's never going to equal "+".  You need to iterate through the members of `BlockChar` and ask `if ch in user:`.  What are you trying to do with "none"?  Do you really want to prevent the word "none" anywhere in the name?

Answer (score 0):

The `any` function and a generator expression will work quite nicely to determine if any of the strings in `BlockChar` are in your `user` string.

```
if any(ch in user for ch in BlockChar):
   ...
```

Comment: Yea that works thanks for it.

Comment: If this answer works for you, feel free to accept it.